# "Null value for 'password'" - PostgreSQL in DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have browsed the web but didn't find any answers/solution to my problem, so i hope somebody here can help me:

I have downloaded DataGrip because i wanted to replace pgAdmin 4. When i try to create a PostgreSQL data source and host it locally, i get the following error: "Null value for 'password'". In pgAdmin 4 i do remember creating a password to access my local database when i first set it up, and it worked fine. However, i don't remember creating a password when installing DataGrip. Is there some default password that im not aware of? And what should be written under "User"?

[image]

Comment: Does pgAdmin allow to create PostgreSQL database instance locally? It looks like that ![it's misunderstanding](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140258/create-pgadmin-database-on-local-machine).

Comment: "*i do remember creating a password to access my local database*" - did you try that password (and user) with DataGrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrip can only connect to the server which already exists (and therefore has a password). "Data source" is the term of DataGrip.

In other words, you need to already have a working database on the server with the known credentials.